# Excel Dynamic Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a total noob when it comes to excel and I don't know if this is possible, basically I have Sheet 1 containing this:

```
A - Names
B - Surnames
C - Telephone Numbers
D - Email Address

G - Names
H - Surnames
I - Telephone Numbers
J - Email Address
```

we update this sheet periodically and I want to copy automatically A and G in Sheet 2 under each other in column A, B and H In Sheet 2 in Column B etc etc...

How can I do this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out pivot tables already?
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-HA102840046.aspx